# Converting Integer to ASCII string

Tags: cryptography

I was reading up on how to convert strings to integer representations for RSA encryption. [See this link.](http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+7.+Public+Key+Cryptography/7.8+Converting+Binary+Strings+to+Integers+for+Use+with+RSA/) Basically, the string-to-integer conversion goes as follows:

```
a(char_1)*256^n + a(char_2)*256^(n-1) + ... + a(char_n)*256^0
```

where

```
n = string length
a(char) = ASCII representation of the character
```

My question is how you would convert from the integer back to the original string. [This link](http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+7.+Public+Key+Cryptography/7.9+Converting+Integers+into+Binary+Strings+for+Use+with+RSA/) says to perform the inverse of the original algorithm, but I don't know how I would go about doing that.

Comment: You seem to have $n+1$ characters, not $n$, if they go from $0$ to $n$.

Comment: You're right. It should be 1 to *n*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a value such as $1415934836.00$ and an expression such as:

$$(x_{3})*256^3+(x_{2})*256^2+(x_{1})*256^1+(x_{0})*256^0=1415934836.00$$

You can perform the iterations below to get the values $x_{i}$ from the second column of the table below (where base=256)

```
Value          Int(Value/Base)  Mod(Value/Base)

1415934836.00  5530995.00       116.00

5530995.00     21605.00         115.00

21605.00       84.00            101.00

84.00          0.00             84.00
```

So we get:

$$(84)*256^3+(101)*256^2+(115)*256^1+(116)*256^0=1415934836.00$$

Notice how similar this is to converting numbers between bases.

Comment: It isn't "similar to changing bases", it *is* changing bases.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying by $256=2^8$ is equivalent to a left shift of $8$ bits. To invert, you basically unshift the bits out, so to speak.

To illustrate, suppose $i$ is the integer. Then, to recover $\text{char_n}$, just take $\text{char_n} = i \,\text{%}\, 256$. To recover $\text{char_n-1}$, do something like $\text{char_n-1} = (i \text{>>} 8) \,\text{%}\,  256$. The pattern should be clear from this.

($\,\text{%}\, $ is the $\mathbb{mod}$ operator, and $\text{>>}$ is the right shift operator.)